# Are there any studies that were able to localize Fusiform Face Area (FFA) for face processing using EEG source localization algorithms?

Tags: perception, eeg, neuroimaging

I am looking for references where people were able to collect 128-256 channel EEG data during face perception task and the map it onto FFA or OFA using source localization algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

The N170 (the face selective component of the brain) is commonly mapped indeed to OFA or FFA. It's trivial to find examples for this, e.g.: [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24185024), [this](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199559053.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199559053-e-017), [this](http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2138698), [this](http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2137096), [this](http://cerco.ups-tlse.fr/pdf0609/itier_rj_04_1261.pdf). Many more studies can be found by searching the relevant data bases, e.g. like [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=n170+source).
Some of these include co-registered EEG/fMRI or MEG. There is some uncertainty of where exactly it originates from - OFA, FFA, both.

Note that dipole fits can be seen as leading to oversparse solutions - they might locate the N170 to one out of OFA or FFA, when it is actually projected by a larger are including OFA, FFA, and possibly even more of the cortex.

Comment: While N170 is a common marker in ERP literature of face processing. What I am really interested is visual processing of faces through time and brain regions. I am interested where brain activates prior, during, and after N170 or other ERPs.

Comment: I think I've answered the question that was asked in this thread. If you want a different question answered, I suggest either asking a new question, or editing this one.